# How to recursively slice through a list and compare adjacent values

Tags: python, list, recursion, tree

`enter code here`Without giving the solution could someone help me understand how to represent this pattern. I think you need to check to see if the nth + 1 > the nth value recursively. Since this is not a list I think I need to use modulo and floor division to walk down the list. However, with only two return statements I don't know how you can recursively call the function and also return True and False.

Problem Statement:
A hole number is a number in which every other digit dips below the digits immediately adjacent to it. For example, the number 968 would be considered a hole number because the number 6 is smaller than both of its surrounding digits. Assume that we only pass in numbers that have an odd number of digits. Define the following function so that it properly identifies hole numbers.

```
def check_hole_number(n):
    """
    >>> check_hole_number(123)
    False
    >>> check_hole_number(3241968)
    True
    >>> check_hole_number(3245968)
    False
    """
    if _________________________________________________________:
        return _________________________________________________________
    return ______________________________________________________________
```

My solution:

```
def check_hole_number(n):
    if n // 10 == 0:
        return True
    return (n % 10) > (n // 10 % 10) and (n // 10 % 10) < (n // 100 % 10) \
    and check_hole_number(n // 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

the patter will be something like:

you have to check the first 3 digits from the current number at each step:

- check (in the `if` statement) if the first 3 numbers respect the `hole number` condition
- if the first 3 digits respect the `hole number` condition than check if at the current step you have the last `3` digits:

  - if you have the 3 last digits then you should return `True` (you have checked already all the rest of your digits and now you are sure that the number is a `hole number`)
  - if you do not have the last 3 digits you have to call again  your function to check the next digits (you have to skip the first 2 digits)
- if the current first 3 digits are not a `hole  number` you should return `False`

```
def check_hole_number(n):
    """
    >>> check_hole_number(123)
    False
    >>> check_hole_number(3241968)
    True
    >>> check_hole_number(3245968)
    False
    """
    if str(n)[1] < str(n)[0] and str(n)[1] < str(n)[2]:
        return True if len(str(n)) == 3 else check_hole_number(str(n)[2:])

    return False
```

---

also, you may check the last 3 digits from the current step:

```
def check_hole_number(n):
    """
    >>> check_hole_number(123)
    False
    >>> check_hole_number(3241968)
    True
    >>> check_hole_number(3245968)
    False
    """
    if n // 10 % 10 < n % 10 and  n // 10 % 10 <  n % 1000 // 100:
        return True if n < 1000 else check_hole_number(n // 100)

    return False
```

Comment: Yea I've figured that if condition out but my problem is making that work with the three lines of code I have to populate. Somehow I need to denote I've made it to the end and return True. I think the base case would be if n // 10 == 0: return True

Comment: @rocket_man you can have a  look of the actual implementation maybe it helps

Comment: Thanks! Yea I wrongly thought it was a list so I implemented a solution that used indexing. Your solution is the same thing I did just using str conversion. However, I figured out how to recursively do it once I figured out the base case. Check the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented an example below that you are welcome to look at for help. If you do not wish to do so, just follow these tips:

As a tip:

1. If you use recursion, you always need a termination condition, otherwise, the function will call itself endlessly, so think about what input should not be used to call the function again. If your function is called (by a recursive call) with this input, just return a value, a boolean and don't call the function again.
2. You are already on the right way to define the recursive, new function call, but is it really n[1:] that serves as new input? Think about it again and play through the function by hand using an example.
3. When is another function call needed? Or in other words: When can you be sure that the input `n` is not a hole number? Set this condition and set the function call depending on whether the condition is true or false.
4. A general hint: variables of type `int` are not subscriptable in Python, so you always have to convert the number into a `str`, i.e. a string representation

! Spoiler ;-) !
An example implementation (only valid under the assumption: `inputNumber mod 2 != 0`)
It can be found here:
https://www.codepile.net/raw/NpoRbalV.py

Comment: Hey kederrac, of course I have read this. I just think that it makes sense for all other users to present the solution as well, for everyone who needs it. For all others, the first sentence indicates that a solution follows which can be ignored.

Comment: Hey kederrac, even if I have different opinions, I have adapted the answer accordingly.

Comment: Your solution wasn't wrong but I only had 3 lines to write the code.